# Strategy for efficiently keeping Facebook friend information up to date (that scales)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time, updates

I've created an application that imports all of your friends and their data.  I cache this data and use the cached data when rendering the app so I'm not forced to import from facebook with every load.

I'm hoping that someone can give me a solid strategy for efficiently keeping friend information on my end up to date (or at least up to date within 24 hours)--real-time updates just tells me if the friends collection/object has changed for a user, not which friends, or what pieces of data.

I could, of course, just re-import every users friend data every day, but that seems like a bit of overkill.

**I want to be able to:**

- Check if a new friend has been added (and then import the new friend)
- Check if any friends have been removed
- Check if any friends have updated their information, along with what information it was that was updated (and then go get the updated information)

Note: The app has thousands of users, and millions of cached friends, so brute forcing it will not scale well

Does anyone have any good information about an effective way of keeping a users friends information up to date without constantly pinging FB to re-import every friend?

Would also be interested in any 3rd party SaaS options for this.

Comment: @ Zachary, Did you already come with an efficient algorithm?

Comment: I use a combination of FB Realtime API and a cronjob that runs a script to import and compare data for X number of users/minute so that every users account is updated at least once every 24 hours. It's more of a burden on the FB API than it is on my system, so hopefully they'll improve their Realtime API to allow for more granular updates.

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried to get actually information about user's friends, and I found only one solution - get full data about all friends every time. I do it on client-side in JS, and send result to our server.